# Is there such a thing as "Suggested favorite name" for a Web page?

Tags: html, browser

Since the importance of good showing in Web search results took over the minds of Web designers, page titles became obnoxiously verbose, along the lines of "Acme Products - your premium source of pretty much everything on Earth" instead of "Acme Products". Because that's what Google would show to would be customers. The side effect of this is that every time you want to add a page to Favorites/Bookmarks, you have to shorten the title to a manageable one.

Is there a spot in HTML - a meta tag or something - where I can specify a short title, fit for placement into Faves, that browsers would recognize? Preferably pre-HTML5.

Comment: [meta description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_description_attribute)?

Comment: With `description` available, will Google display it instead of title?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev — No, instead of an except from the page … sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

None that I'm aware of. If your title is too long to make a good Favorites entry, you may want to consider tightening it up a bit.

Comment: +1 - write titles for readers, don't keyword stuff them until they explode.

Comment: If I tighten it up, my Google click-through rate will suffer. That's the whole point. I personally like my favorite titles to be 20-40 characters long.

Comment: Google cuts off titles at 60 characters, though. If you're using longer titles than that, nobody's seeing the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a tag for providing a shortened title such as you're suggesting. You may be able to what you via javascript but I'm not sure about that as I would assume that browser bookmarks always head straight for the title tag.